# how to display and play html5 audio in dot php file?

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

The audio is not displaying in php file but the same audio is working on .html file. How to fix it can anyone help me please? Thanks

```
 <audio control>
  <source src="samples/narcon.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
```

Comment: Err... rename it to `.php` and run it off a server?

Comment: Use ctrl+u or the dev tool of your browser to check the source of the generated code. Do you find your html code ?

Comment: @MelvynMarigny Thanks I checked it yes Its displaying in dev tool but not showing in index.php page..

Comment: @MelvynMarign Do u have any solution?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of the cool things about php is that you can close and reopen the tag when needed so if you have the php file open you can do something like this

```
<?php
     some php code is here
?>

     <audio control>
       <source src="samples/narcon.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
     </audio>
<?php
code after the html
?> //end of php file
```